# I have a problem on printing elements In an array so that any two repeated elements appear once

Tags: java

The question was to find the distinct occurance of numbers in an array such that any element that appears twice is only printed once.

```
public class ICT_Qoestions_34 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Index of Numbers");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        int[] myList = RandomNumber(n);

        System.out.println("Distinct Numbers"); here I called a method that has a parameter of arrays coming from the RandomNumber() method.
        DistinctNumbers(myList);

    }

    // Generating Random Numbers And Pouplating them in an Array whose Rerference is myList

    //Question 1
    public static int[] RandomNumber(int n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            System.out.println("PLEASE Enter Positive Number!");
        }
        int[] myList = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            int Values = (int) ((90 * Math.random()) + 10);
            System.out.print(Values + "\t");
            for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {

                myList[j] = Values;

            }

        }
        return myList;
    }
```

The Above method works beautifully and generates an array of n indexed random numbers.

The problem arose in this method as it is not doing the work I was expecting and I couldn't trace my mistake.

```
public static void DistinctNumbers(int[] myList) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myList.length; j++) {
            int key = myList[j];
            int Occurance = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
                if (myList[i] == myList[j] && i != j) 
                    Occurance++;
                }
```

if the occurance of a number is =1, No problem but when it is >1 we should look out cause our orders were to print them only once. And so i did this...

```
                if (Occurance== 1) 
                    System.out.println(myList[j] + "\t");
                else if(Occurance>1){
                for (int k=0; k<j;k++){
```

if elements of an array until the jth index match with that of the jth index, we break the loop to avoid any repeted priting in the console.

```
                if (myList[k]==key)
                    break;
                else if(myList[k]!=key){
```

if elements of an array until the jth index never match with that of the jth index, we Print that distinct number then break the loop to avoid any repeated printing in the console. I believe this is efficient cause if fo example 15 is found in the 3rd and 15th index, the third will be printed and the 15th will be jumped.

```
                    System.out.println(myList[j] + "\t");
                break;
                }
                }

                }
           } 

        }
    }
```

but that doesnt seem to be the outcome and I couldnt find nothing when I traced it...

Comment: Hint: dont mix code and explanations like that. Focus on writing up a [mcve], and document requirements, expected and actual output separately. That makes it much easier to first understand the problem, to then read the code. And avoid "explaining what is printed. Show us what gets printed, with a minimal example.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was just introduced to Stackoverflow. That's why I confused the two...

Comment: Sure, no problem. But as said: if you want others to help you, you should make that as easy as possible. Also note: you want read about Java naming conventions. Method names go camelCase() in java!

Answer (score 0):

Well you should consider changing your algorithm a bit. For loop with occurrence count not gonna work. What's your best is a while and small method which checks the generated random number is there in the array or not.

```
while(isElementExist(generatedNum,arr)) {
   generatedNum = (int) ((90 * Math.random()) + 10);
}
// insert into array now.
```

Answer (score 0):

solution can be made very simple by using set

```java
void printDistinct(int a[]){
    Set<Integer> distinctElements=new LinkedHashSet<>();
    distinctElements.addAll(Arrays.asList(a));
    for(int e:distinctElements){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which of course drops the ordering/sorting of that array. You should mention that, and maybe suggest to use a LinkedHashSet that keeps insertion order.

Comment: I have update my answer that uses linkedHashSet that way we can still mentain order of elements as well.